# Comparing, Replacing, Matching Arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am currently trying to decipher a text file that was handed to me. I am to use an array ex:  where alphabet_size = 26

```
char code[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {'i','z','t', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'q', 'r', 'k', 'g', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'c', 's', 'v', 'w'
    , 'f', 'u', 'y', 'p', 'j', 'x',}
```

to decipher another char array file using that contains this

```
ifqkwxcadf ar cei fpoi masif cd cei xkdqirr du pxxnwafm pf pnmdkaceo cd p oirrpmi, teaqe rqkpohnir cei gpcp af ac-oplafm ac sikw gauuaqvnc pfg caoi qdfrvoafm, au fdc xkpqcaqpnnw aoxdrrahni, cd gigvqi cei dkamafpn masif dfnw cei ifqdgig gpcp. afxvcr cd cei pnmdkaceo cwxaqpnnw afsdnsi pggacadfpn riqkic gpcp qpnnig liwr, teaqe xkisifcr cei oirrpmi ukdo hiafm giqdgig-isif au cei pnmdkaceo ar xvhnaqnw lfdtf.
```

What I've tried is (to not use the char code array but use an if statement to check if the encrypted message[0]  = 'a' then message[0] = 'i'

```
    for (int num = 0; message[num] != '\0'; num++)
    {
        if (message[num] == 'a') { message[num] = 'i'; }
        if (message[num] == 'b') { message[num] = 'z'; }
        if (message[num] == 'c') { message[num] = 't'; }
        if (message[num] == 'd') { message[num] = 'o'; }
        if (message[num] == 'e') { message[num] = 'h'; }
```

but ended up with another weird message

```
elcujpjeml eu jbe lame geuel jm jbe pumceuu mf appljelg al algmuejbm jm a meuuage, jbecb ucuambleu jbe daja el ej-makelg ej ueuj deffeculj ald jeme cmluumelg, ef lmj puacjecallj empmuueble, jm deduce jbe muegelal geuel mllj jbe elcmded daja. elpuju jm jbe algmuejbm jjpecallj elumlue addejemlal uecuej daja called keju, jbecb pueuelju jbe meuuage fumm beelg decmded-euel ef jbe algmuejbm eu publeclj klmjl.
```

and so on and son.. (That means each 'a' in the input text should be replaced with an 'i', each 'b' with a 'z' and so forth.) (message contains the encrypted text file I showed up there)
Now, my question is how do I use "char code array" to encrypt the "message array" basically not sure if this is the right term but match and replace? Any help would be great! Thank you in advance.

Comment: May not be the complete answer but at least turn those into `else if`s or put a `continue` in each block, otherwise if the letter is "a" it gets changed to "i" and then to whatever "i" gets changed to, etc before moving to the next index. A debugger should show you this. But outside of that there is most certainly a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing through the `code` array.

```
for (int num = 0; message[num] != '\0'; num++)
    if(isalpha(message[num]))
        message[num] = code[message[num]-'a'];
```

p.s.: `#include <ctype.h>` for the `isalpha` function. It is used here because you only want to substitute *alphabetic* characters (and you're using only lowercase letters).

As in the comment above, your mistake was that you were substituting some characters more than once because you did not use `else if`.

Finally, here's your decrypted plaintext:

> encryption is the name given to the process of applying an algorithm to a message, which scrambles the data in it-making it very difficult and time consuming, if not practically impossible, to deduce the original given only the encoded data. inputs to the algorithm typically involve additional secret data called keys, which prevents the message from being decoded-even if the algorithm is publicly known